I cannot get the permission window to appear using "requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions)"
I'm trying to request the permissions that my app needs but I can't get the permission window to appear.
Here is my composable :
@Composable
fun IntroScreen(
    introViewModel: IntroViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavController
){

    val requestPermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { permissionsMap ->
        permissionsMap.forEach { (permission, isGranted) ->
            Log.i("tag", "Permission: $permission, Granted: $isGranted")
        }
    }

    val permissions = introViewModel.permissions
    val permissionsState by introViewModel.permissionsState.collectAsState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

    ){
        Button(onClick = {
            Log.i("tag", "Permissions state: ${permissionsState.joinToString(separator = ", ")}")
            val allPermissionsGranted = permissionsState.all { it }
            Log.i("tag", "All permissions granted: $allPermissionsGranted")

            if (!allPermissionsGranted) {
                // Request permissions
                Log.i("tag", "Requesting permissions inside if statement: ${permissions.joinToString(", ")}")
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions)
            } else {
                Log.i("tag", "All permissions already granted")
            }
       }, shape = Shapes.small) {
            Text(text = "Ask Permissions")

    }
}

Here is my view model:
@HiltViewModel
class IntroViewModel @Inject constructor(private val context: Context, introInteractor:IntroInteractor):ViewModel(){

    private val _permissionsState = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Boolean>())
    val permissionsState: StateFlow<List<Boolean>> get() = _permissionsState

    val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
    )

    init {
        updatePermissionsState()
    }

    fun updatePermissionsState() {
        val permissionsStateList = permissions.map { permission ->
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
        _permissionsState.value = permissionsStateList
    }
}

I made the code as simple as I could. And all the logged statement returns the expected results. The Internet, bluetooth and bluetooth permissions are true and the rest are false. I tried removing the ones that are true, but I didn't get the window to appear.
My code reaches the "requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions)" and the parameters for the launch() are correct. Why can't I get the window to appear?
This is the log result inside my if statement before my launcher:
"Requesting permissions inside if statement: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, android.permission.BLUETOOTH, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.INTERNET
".
N.B.: I'm testing on a real Galaxy A14 and my manifest file is :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>


You say "Some are true and some are false" that means you denied some permissions at least once, if they get denied twice you dont get the permission dialog anymore and the user has to manually go an turn them on

Also only a handful of those permissions are one you have to ask for, the other wont even show the dialog. Please review what permissions actually need to be asked for that the user needs to grant

I never granted any permissions. It's the Internet, bluetooth and bluetooth admin that are automatically true, but the request permission window doesn't appear even if I remove them.

After spending few hours got the root cost of the issue , that is ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.
From here

ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission shouldn't be requested before
the general location permission was granted (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION). Otherwise, the system will just ignore the
request.

so create separate ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission launcher and run after success of (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
More details Background location access checklist
